# I am trying to install jenkins on centos using command - "sudo yum install jenkins -y"

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos, devops

I am getting the following error

Last metadata expiration check: 1:04:29 ago on Mon 18 Oct 2021 01:38:53 PM UTC.

No match for argument: jenkins

Error: Unable to find a match: jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` , you should configure a correct repository

Take a look here : https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/

Comment: This looks like it could be a useful answer. Please edit your answer to include the actual steps that they need to take. (Links can break!)